# PromiseKit pod installed correctly, but import PromiseKit returns error?

Tags: swift, xcode, promisekit

I am developing an app on Xcode 8.2.1 utilizing swift 3. I have a few asynchronous task that I need lined in an appropriate order and so I have decided to use PromiseKit for this purpose. I added a podfile to my project directory and modified then installed it using `pod install` (via cocoapods). The install worked appropriately as my command line gave me this success message:
[image]

(This by the way is the podfile text):
[image]

I added the framework to my linked frameworks and libraries for the project as shown below:
[image]

With all of this done, I expected that I would be able to utilize `import PromiseKit` at the top of my viewControllers in order to access the functions in the framework's library. However, typing `import PromiseKit` gave me the following error:
[image]

Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Comment: Build the project once and see if the error persists.

Comment: @ebby94 the error does indeed still persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this particular issues stems from using the wrong version of the `PromiseKit`. I was running the `pod install` without defining what version of `PromiseKit` should be, hoping that this ambiguity would allow the install to pick the most up to date version. (Also, initially specifying the version, as is suggested on the website:

```
swift_version = "3.0"
pod "PromiseKit", "~> 4.0"
```

would return an error that I couldn't access the 4.0). This error was:

```
` 'PromiseKit (~>4.0)' required by 'Podfile' 
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency:...
```

This turned out to be the overall issue (that I needed to use the 4.0 specification). To get rid of this error I ran the following commands:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install #in the project directory... after modifying the podfile to the code
#written above... ie. including the '"~> 4.0"'
```

The repo and setup take some time, though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case iOS Deployment target was outdated for the Pod Targets.

To resolve, select Pods in the Project navigation, select Pods targets, and update [iOS Deployment Target] in the Build Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you install the pod, you need to open .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproject. Moreover, as you have already installed the pod for PromiseKit, there is no need to link the framework again. Just open .xcworkspace in xcode and you should able to import the PromiseKit.

Comment: I tried this as well. I redid the whole process and open the .xcworkspace without doing the additional framework link and I still get the error